# menu handling in F#

Tags: wpf, menu, callback, f#

I have added menu control to the form, F# coding

```
<Menu Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="283,13,0,0" Name="menutGoto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78">
<MenuItem />
    <MenuItem Header="Go to..." FontSize="14">
        <MenuItem Header="test 1" />
        <MenuItem Header="Test 2" />
        <MenuItem Header="Test 3" />
        <MenuItem Header="Hello" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

I'm new in Visual Studio 2010 programming. I'm building a customized program that will run on Windows XP/7, my friend helped me to start this using F#, I added menu control with 5 menu items on the form but I don't know how to make it work, like displaying message "Hello" when a command item is clicked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't nearly enough information to help you.  At least define what you mean by "work?"

Comment: What ui framework are you using?  Can you explain more clearly what it is you're trying to accomplish?  Can you detail a bit more about where you're getting stuck in achieving this on your own?  It is much easier to help if you give a bit more context.

Comment: I posted the question. I'm new in Visual Studio 2010 programming. I'm building a customized program that will run on Windows XP/7, my friend helped me to start this using F#, I added menu control with 5 menu items on the form but I don't know how to make it work, like displaying message "Hello" when a command item is clicked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have time to properly answer this question, but you can derive your own answer from here: http://wpftutorial.net/Menus.html

Comment: The link you provided was exactly what I'm looking for, my problem is now solved. thank you so much mydogisbox

Answer (score 2):

The menu items can be bound to commands specified in a data context using data binding.

Modify the XAML to bind to a command:

```
<MenuItem Header="test 1" 
          Command="{Binding MenuCommand}" 
          CommandParameter="Hello"/>
```

Create a type for the data context with a `MenuCommand` property which returns an `ICommand`:

```
type DataContext () =
  member context.MenuCommand = 
    command (fun arg -> MessageBox.Show(arg.ToString()) |> ignore)
```

`ICommand` can be implemented using an [F# object expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233237.aspx):

```
let command exec =
    let event = Event<_,_>()
    { new ICommand with
        member __.CanExecute(_) = true
        member __.Execute(arg) = exec arg
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member __.CanExecuteChanged = event.Publish
    }
```

Then simply set the window's `DataContext` to an instance of the `DataContext` type:

```
mainWindow.DataContext <- DataContext()
```

Full source code: https://bitbucket.org/ptrelford/simplewpfapp/src

Alternatively the view can be built via code instead of XAML:

```
let helloCommand =
    command (fun _ -> MessageBox.Show("Hello") |> ignore)

let gotoMenuItem =
    MenuItem(Header="Go to...", FontSize=14.,
             ItemsSource = [
                MenuItem(Header="test 1")
                MenuItem(Header="Test 2")
                MenuItem(Header="Test 3")
                MenuItem(Header="Hello",Command=helloCommand)
             ])

let mainMenu =
    Menu(Width=78.,Height=27.,Margin=Thickness(283.,13.,0.,0.),
         HorizontalAlignment=HorizontalAlignment.Left,
         VerticalAlignment=VerticalAlignment.Top,
         ItemsSource=[MenuItem();gotoMenuItem])
```

To run, set the window's content to the mainMenu:

```
[<STAThread>]
do  let window = Window(Content=mainMenu)
    (Application()).Run(window) |> ignore
```

Comment: This work for me thank you all for the help                       <Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="_File">
        <MenuItem Header="_New..."  Click="New_Click"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>